# How to Display a picture from gallery

Tags: android, layout, gallery

I have a gallery (this gallery is mixed with some embedded component in linerlayout) presenting some thumbnails. What I want to do is , whenever user clicks on any of the picture that picture should be displayed in full screen. Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass in this image to the Gallery and have it display this image.

Looking at the Gallery Manifest:

```
<activity android:name="com.android.camera.ImageGallery"
                android:label="@string/gallery_label"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_gallery">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/image" />
            </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

With this info is it clear that you can pass in an Intent with the ACTION_VIEW and set the data as the image, which can be a URI which could be like "file:/". Then when starting this intent you may want to startActivityForResult(), so that the application can come back to you. Refer to the Gallery Source code.

Answer (score 0):

For the ImageView you pass into the gallery you could do

```
ImageView i;
i.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
//also, you shoudn't use hardcoded pixel values (in
i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(400, 300));)
```